A contradiction of ideas that serves as the determining factor in their interaction. This situation created the inner dialectic of American history

One of the definitions of 'dialectic' is a contradiction of ideas that serves as the determining factor in their interaction. And below is corresponding example.


ex) This situation created the inner dialectic of American history.

What's the meaning of the sentence above and what could be the best rephrased sentence?

This situation created the inner contradiction of ideas that serves as the inner determining factor of American history.

@MichaelHarvey You could expound on the sentence with other easier words without a tautology.

What, exactly, do you not understand?

*create the inner dialectic of

Inner = central, fundamental, etc. Possibly, in this context, also 'not visible on the surface' or 'not superficially apparent'. Or, I suggest,  'hidden from people who don't understand Marxist philosophy'.

Source? Citations (quotes) should be attributed.

This is not an English question. Vote to close.

@Lambie The word 'dialectic' is not an easy one , especially for non-native speakers of English just like me. This word is very abstract and the question is worth answering. Please be generous to English Language Learners.

I'm sure it's in a bilingual dictionary unless you speak a very minor language. Also, it does not sound like a good description of American culture.

We have to use physical metaphors to describe "dialectic" because it is an abstract concept. A dialectic refers to a situation in which two opposing "societal forces" pull against each other in a kind of "tug-of-war". The resulting social "tensions" are the defining feature of the situation as it develops over time.  The term dialectic is used to refer to that tension as the society's definining characteristic, its "determining factor".  It is that which causes it to be what and how it is.

In the early 1970s I was studying English at college, and it seemed that all of the cool chicks were in the Young Communists (which had a branch on campus). I joined, but a big problem I had was that I just couldn't get my head around what 'dialectical materialism' was. And I don't think I'm stupid! Also how dull the meetings were. A girl who I fancied scornfully told me that I was a 'leftist adventurer'. I think that also my beard wasn't good enough.

@MichaelHarvey A pair of Trotsky glasses may have been all you needed to get that party started.
